# Unix @ symbol does not work

Tags: unix, sqlplus, hp-ux

I'm using a HP-UX B.11.31 U and I needed to acess sqlplus but for some reason when I write a @ unix erases the line. So when I try to copy past user/pass@//host:port/SID I get //host:port/SID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting your argument into quotes 'user/pass@//host:port/SID'?

Comment: the momento @ shows up the line is erased so even if I have 'teste' and then try to add a @ before the last ' I get '

Comment: @EdmundSimpson That sounds like '@' is interpreted as the line kill character? Last seen on a terminal in the early 90s. Try `stty kill ^u` to set line-erase command: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102940/how-do-you-find-what-keys-the-erase-and-line-kill-characters-are-in-ubuntu

Comment: stty kill ^u command worked PERFECTLY a huge thx for the help